# random pathway generating algo within time constraints

Tags: random, nodes

I wanted to understand how a random pathway generating algo with 6 data points - source value, destination value and two extreme distance points within a an enclosed time constarint might be created. meaning if we use time - 10:00 AM as start point at location A and 10 PM as finish point at B and has to reach C which can be a certain distance from A and D another point that should be reached at a specefied time total 12 hours in between being the duration to contruct the path but it also has to be at destaination time by the 10 PM time. i want to be able to give it these 4 values each time with the specefic times to reach them and also its free to wallow with in the given area of distance and i want it to generate different pattern pathways from 10:00 Am to the extereme points and then back to the destination value by 10 PM so i want it to generate random pathways to the specefied points i give it each time by varying the time interval to reach how can nodes be applied to this idea?

i dont know if this makes sense i am not a programer but i want to hear you intelligent folks ideas on this concept